# Append closing then opening HTML tag with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a scenario and in that I want to append a closing tag then some other tag after that opening Tag of the first closed Tag.
For Example: I have this code **`<ins>123678</ins>`** and I want to append **`<b>46</b>`** in between `3` and `6`. I tried this code while putting my cursor in between `3` and `6`

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,'</ins><b>45</b><ins>');
```

But it is not giving me desired output. I want my output like this

```
<ins>123</ins><b>45</b><ins>678</ins>
```

Comment: This is not possible. You can only append a complete HTML element. If it requires opening & closing tags, then you have to include them. If you don't then the browser will automatically correct your mistake and add the necessary tag to the source for you.

Comment: You have to get the whole content and wrap each section which the corresponding tag. Inserting "a half tag", even if the end result is then valid, is not possible. You have to wrap 123 and 678 with `<ins> </ins>` , remove the initial ins and add the `<b>45</b>`

Comment: Why `<ins>123</ins><b>45</b><ins>678</ins>`? Ain't `<ins>123<b>45</b>678</ins>` simpler?

Comment: @Thomas this is the requirement.

Comment: Then you can either [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) `<ins>123678</ins>` with `<ins>123</ins><b>45</b><ins>678</ins>` or change `<ins>123678</ins>` to `<ins>123</ins>` and then insert `<b>45</b><ins>678</ins>` [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) the node. There's no way to insert an ending tag. The bigger issue is when you need to reverse this change so that you can highlight a different part *(I have a feeling that this is/will be the next requirement)*

Comment: Why not `<ins>123<b>45</b>678</ins>` and handle the style with css?

Comment: @freedomn-m we have already done this with CSS but requirement is that without CSS and only with Tags

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace

> `<ins>123678</ins>`

with

> `newHTML`= `"<ins>123"`+`"<b>45</b>"`+`"678</ins>"`

using jquery

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).